# How can I calibrate sensors programmatically, instead of manually setting of *#0*#?

Tags: sensors, virtual-reality, calibration, drift

Hellow, I'm writting a vr apps but it has drift in cardboard.

I found the solution which is sensor calibration with a secrit code "*#0*#".

But I want to make a code programmatically

to do the selftest of sensors to calibrate them.

I searched but couldn't find api for the sensor calibration of a smartphone.

So I searched a example or source code for the sensor calibration, but couldn't.

Please let me know some api or logic for sensor calibration.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

By "calibration", I assume you mean "adjust for gravity" with the accelerometer, and "establish a basis transform" for the gyroscope and/or position and external transform sensors?

Without some kind of go-to-reference, like a magnometer (which must be calibrated to local magnetic field data, at some point), or pre-calibrated external sensor data (like the Rift, Vive, and PSVR use), you can't calibrate motion sensors without manual intervention.

You can establish a basis by suggesting to the user, via a fullscreen presentation/text, that they stand still for a moment, in a comfortable position, perhaps while presenting a "Calibrating..." screen while you gather data, but that's about as automated as you can really make your calibration.

Sadly, you'll inevitably get "drift" in gyro and accelerometer data, without a magnometer (which are not typically present in phones), or other form of correction (like a recalibration, triggered by a button press).  This is unavoidable at the hardware level -- there's no magic to avoiding it.

You might be able to create a software adjustment solution, after measuring drift over an extended period, by asking the user to place the device on a surface for some period of time, while you gather data.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I just wanted to do the calibration of the test page programmatically, but I doesn't know how to do it. And I made a conclusion that I should program at the level of hardware or firmware. I think I cannot do this for now.